# Conditional SQL INSERT INTO query

Tags: sql

I would like to add data to a field in a particular row without having SQL create a new row.

I know you can't use WHERE unless it's a SELECT statement, but is there something similar to achieve the same result?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable WHERE ID = " + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + " (A) " + "VALUES (@0)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the UPDATE clause rather than the INSERT since you need to change data in existing row rather than insert a new row

Comment: If you want to change data in an existing row use the UPDATE statement instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `update`, and it would look like:

```
update mytable
    set col = @0
    where id = " + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId + " (A) ";
```

This is a sketch of what the code looks like.  For instance, I don't know the name of the column you want to update.